# What is the use of entropy (`/dev/random/) in android?

Tags: android, ubuntu, random

I read this blog post over [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1987032&nocache=0).

The post says that Chrome, map application uses `/dev/random`. I wonder why they use them. Is that `/dev/random`generates random numbers with the help of hardware?

Is this the case only in android or it happens to be in linux os too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random

Answer (score 1):

You should check this other [XDA article](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/entropy-seed-generator-not-all-its-hacked-up-to-be/).

They say that `/dev/random` is not used by most of the applications and that the performance gains are probably due to boosting of the CPU speed.